# TCP - C++ - No matching function for call to

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I am trying to make a basic program that transfer data via TCP.

Here is the client file:

## Header

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

## Code

```
#include "socketclient.hpp"
#include <arpa/inet.h>

socketclient::socketclient () {
    iSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&saiAddress, '0', sizeof(saiAddress));

    saiAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saiAddress.sin_port = htons(3000);
    saiAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    inet_pton(AF_INET, INADDR_ANY, &saiServerAddress.sin_addr);

    connect(iSocket, (struct saiAddress *)&saiServerAddress, sizeof(saiServerAddress));

    send(iSocket, sVal, strlen(sVal.c_str()), 0);
}
```

However, for some reason the compiler says `No matching function` for `inet_pton`, `connect`, and `send`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> inet_pton(AF_INET, INADDR_ANY, &saiServerAddress.sin_addr);

You can't pass `INADDR_ANY` to `inet_pton()` like that.  It is expecting a `char*` string instead, eg:

```
inet_pton(AF_INET, "an IP address here", &saiServerAddress.sin_addr);
```

And BTW, you can't `connect()` a TCP socket to `INADDR_ANY` (0.0.0.0) anyway.  You need to specify the actual IP address of the listening server.

> connect(iSocket, (struct saiAddress *)&saiServerAddress, sizeof(saiServerAddress));

You can't pass a `saiAddress*` to `connect()`, it is expecting a `sockaddr*` instead, eg:

```
connect(iSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&saiServerAddress, sizeof(saiServerAddress));
```

Make sure `saiServerAddress` is declared as `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_storage` (or at least make sure that `saiAddress` is binary-compatible with them).

> send(iSocket, sVal, strlen(sVal.c_str()), 0);

You can't pass a `std::string` to `send()` like that. It is expecting a `void*` instead (and you shouldn't be using `strlen(sVal.c_str())`, use `sVal.size()` instead), eg:

```
send(iSocket, sVal.c_str(), sVal.size(), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem perfectly! That also makes some more sense, thank you for your pointers and tips - very helpful.